# How to update app when new data is available

Tags: ios

I'm fairly new to app development and am having trouble figuring this out. One part of my app involves a messaging platform. Right now I am using a php web server to connect to MySQL backend. I have all the functionality of a messaging app, but I am unsure how to push new messages when they are available.

One basic solution would be to call my function to check for new messages every x amount of seconds, but obviously that's not a good solution. I have looked into Apple Push Notification Service and am unsure if this would fit my needs. When I looked into it this seems to be for sending notifications to the user remotely. However, rather than the user getting these messages displayed I would like the app to call a function instead (the function would load the new messages). Is this possible with push notifications?

Also this app is on both iOS and Android, so if there is a (possibly third party) solution that would cover both it would be ideal.

Any insight into this problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to check [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com) and their Firebase Realtime Database. It's a paid service, check what's covered in the free version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll demo it with the free version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a push notification and the app is in the foreground, the `AppDelegate` has a [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) called which allows you to execute whatever method you want.

This is only for iOS though, I don't know know it's handled in Android.